# My PHP Search Function isn't Outputting Data

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to create a way of searching my website. I've created a search bar on my index page. You can find this page here: http://seersvillage.com/v1.2/

My search form looks like this:

```
        <form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="search" value="Skeleton" onFocus="this.value=''">
    </form>
```

and I have a functions.php file attatched and this page is also connected to my mysql database. I have content available to be read / searched for all ready.

Here is my search function on functions.php:

```
function doSearch() {
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' or description LIKE '%$searchq%' or content LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'there was no search results!';
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $eName = $row['name'];
            $eDesc = $row['description'];
            $eCont = $row['content'];
            $id = $row['id'];

            $output .= '<div>'.$eName.' '.$eDesc.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the only thing on my search.php (excluding your usual html layout) is as follows:

```
<?php

include('includes/functions.php');

if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}

?>
```

and further down in the  tags.

```
<?php print("$output");?>
```

Now I am pretty new to PHP and MySQL. However I am getting no error on my error.log file, making troubleshooting a little hard for a first timer. Any suggestions? I'm sure it's a very simple mistake, probably just misspelt something, but I just can't see it.

Comment: as mentioned below... you aren't returning anything, but there are more problems than just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `doSearch` function does not return anything.

`return $output;`

But $output is only declared within the function. So you'll need to use

`print(doSearch());`

Either that or declare $output as a global variable, but we don't want to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your php.ini file is set to not display errors. Add these lines of code at the beginning of your code and retry:

`<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSearch() {
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' or description LIKE '%$searchq%' or content LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'there was no search results!';
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $eName = $row['name'];
            $eDesc = $row['description'];
            $eCont = $row['content'];
            $id = $row['id'];

            $output .= '<div>'.$eName.' '.$eDesc.'</div>';
        }
    }

 //make sure your function returns $output
 return $output;
}
```

Make sure your function returns the output and then echo out the function:

```
<?php echo doSearch(); ?>
```

This is because of how PHP variables are [scoped](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

...then of course we need to add in all the standard provisos ... **don't** use the `mysql_` library it's almost as dead as a Norwegian Blue. If you use mysqli or PDO you can bind the parameters/values to a prepared statement and not only will that improve efficiency but it'll ensure your input is properly sanitised (far better than that odd ad-hoc `preg_replace` you're using).

You don't want to kill your script (`die`) when the query fails - that's just a bit weird, handle the error properly.

There are far better ways to do searches in SQL such as [FULLTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) searches.. or if you can, perhaps implement [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) rather than trying to roll your own.